# When typing command "npm run dev" for webpack, it creates a folder that ends with NaN

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

i'm taking a course in Lynda.com "learning-full-stack-javascript-development-mongodb-node-and-react" and when i use the command "npm run dev" to create a bundle.js file in "public" folder, it creates a folder "publicNaN" and puts the file bundle.js in it.
i want it to be in the "public" folder.

here is the webpack.config.js file:

```js
const path = require("path");

const BUILD_PATH = path.join(__dirname, "./public");

// See https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/master/extensions/shared.webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
    mode: "production",
    target: "node",
    node: {
        __dirname: false
    },
    entry: {
        extension: ["./src/index.js"]
    },
    output: {
        path: BUILD_PATH + + '/public',
        filename: "bundle.js",
        libraryTarget: "commonjs",
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".ts", ".js"]
    },
    externals: {
        "vscode": "commonjs vscode"
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "ts-loader"
                    }
                ],
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
                test: /\.mjs$/,
                type: "javascript/auto",
                use: []
            }
        ]
    },
    stats: {
        children: false,
        modules: false
    }
};
```

Comment: you mistyped `BUILD_PATH + +`, which incremented it as a number

Comment: The second `+` tried to turn `/public` into a number, resulting in `NaN` (not a number). You'll want: `path: BUILD_PATH`, given that BUILD_PATH already ends in /public.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're already setting your BUILD_PATH to /public here:

```
const BUILD_PATH = path.join(__dirname, "./public");
```

So there's no need to add it in the output object. Also the two + signs tries to convert to a number. That's why you get NaN at the end.

So change the output object to this:

```
output: {
   path: BUILD_PATH,
   filename: "bundle.js",
   libraryTarget: "commonjs",
},
```

Comment: This answer is perfectly fine but like I already mentioned, the `+ +` tries to turn `'/public'` into a number (not increment BUILD_PATH). `13 + '10'` results in the string `'1310'`, but `13 + + '10'` evaluates to the number `23`. Also, this is a typo question. Flag it as such, instead of answering.

Comment: Your're perfectly correct there. I used the wrong words there. I meant convert it to a number not increment. Will edit the post. And where do I type it as a typo question? Haven't been here that long so sorry but don't know how that works. So I'm not supposed to give a clear answer?

Comment: The question is off-topic for stackoverflow, so no, you're not supposed to answer it. stackoverflow is not so much about helping individuals fix their problems but about building a repository of useful questions and answers. This question was answered in the comments because the OP still needs help with it, but since it's just a typo, it will not benefit anybody else and soon be closed or even removed. As soon as you're able, check the `close` link beneath a question and study the options that are available. As soon as a question matches those, don't answer it, just flag it.

Comment: Ok I understand now. Thank you for the info.